# Resize Excel chart to fit X-Axis labels in horizontal lines (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create vba to modify charts. I was successful with doing tasks like adding title, legends, labels, etc.

But I'm stuck on one task of resizing the chart to fit the X-axis labels in horizontal lines.

I understand that I can resize the chart with ActiveChart.Parent.Height and ActiveChart.Parent.Width. There I can only resize to the height or width is known.

Attaching Original and desired size screenshots for better clarity.

**Original Size (With X-Axis labels as vertical lines)**
[image: Original Size]

**Desired Size (With X-Axis labels as horizontal lines)**
[image: Desired Size]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.